# How to add a class to td after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this html structure:

```
<th><?php echo $decrypted_subscribers_name; ?></th>
<td><?php echo $decrypted_subscribers_email; ?></td>
<td class="category">Offside></td>
```

`<td class="category">` has several values. When the value is `Offside`, i add a class to make it italic en red color:

```
// red color & italic Offside category
$('.category:contains("Offside")').closest('.category').addClass('text-danger font-italic');
```

When i do an ajax request and reload the div (in which all the `td's`), it does not add the class `text-danger font-italic` anymore. 
So i added this line after the success in ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "admin.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {     
        file_id : file_id,
        category : category                             
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);            
        $(".subscribers-list").load(location.href + " .subscribers-list"); // reload subscribers-list div

    }

}).done(function() {
  $('.category:contains("Offside")').closest('.category').addClass('text-danger font-italic');
});
```

Unfortunately, it does not add the class `text-danger font-italic` to the td.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Because `done` is for first ajax request. Ajax-request via `.load` is not considered.

Comment: Ok. But how can i make this work properly?

Comment: I don't know the content which is loaded, but why cant you add required classes on __server__?

Comment: try to add class in success of ajax call